# $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int_{(0,1)^n}f\left(\left(\frac1n\sum _{x=1}^n x_i^a\right)^\frac{1}{a}\right)dx_1\cdots dx_n$

Tags: integration, limits, probability-theory, average

Given $x_1, \cdots, x_n>0$, $a\in\mathbb R$ and $f\in C[0,1]$, then can we compute
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int_{(0,1)^n}f\left(\left(\frac1n \sum _{i=1}^n x_i^a\right)^\frac{1}{a}\right)dx_1\cdots dx_n$$
In terms of $f, a$? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by the term $(0,1)^n$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probability theory makes the answer very simple. The limit exists and equals $f((\frac  1 {a+1})^{1/a}) $ at least when $a >-1$.

Let $(U_i)$ be i.i.d random variables uniformly distributed on $(0,1)$. By SLLN $\frac  1n \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} U_i^{a} \to \int_0^{1} x^{a}dx=\frac 1 {a+1}$ almost surely. Hence the given integral tends to  $f((\frac 1 {a+1})^{1/a})$.

Comment: When $a <-1$ the limit exists and equals $f(0)$. (SLLN has  a version for the infinite mean case also).  @MHZ